# create schema using struct in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and trying to make custom schema from array of elements to read files based on a new custom schema.

I am reading the arrays from json file and used explode method and created a dataframe for each element in column array.

```
val otherPeople = sqlContext.read.option("multiline", "true").json(otherPeopleDataset)
val column_values = otherPeople.withColumn("columns", explode($"columns")).select("columns.*")
column_values.printSchema()
```

obtained output is :

```
column_values: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column_id: string, data_sensitivty: string ... 3 more fields]
root
 |-- column_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data_sensitivty: string (nullable = true)
 |-- datatype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- length: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

val column_values = ddb_schema.withColumn("columns", explode($"columns")).select("columns.*")
val column_name = column_values.select("name", "datatype", "length")

column_name.show(4)


 +------------------+--------+------+
 |              name|datatype|length|
 +------------------+--------+------+
 |     object_number| varchar|   100|
 |     function_type| varchar|   100|
 |             hof_1| decimal|  17,3|
 |             hof_2| decimal|  17,2|
 |            region| varchar|   100|
 |           country| varchar|  null|
 +------------------+--------+------+
```

Now for all the values listed above i am trying to creating val schema dynamically using below
code

```
val schemaColumns = column_name.collect()
val schema = schemaColumns.foldLeft(new StructType())(
  (schema, columnRow) => schema.add(columnRow.getAs[String]("name"), getFieldType(columnRow.getAs[String]("datatype")), true)
  )

def getFieldType(typeName: String): DataType = typeName match {
    case "varchar" => StringType
    // TODO include other types here
    case _ => StringType
  }
```

problem with above is that i am able to get the datatypes in struct, **but i would also like to get (scale and preicion) only for datatype decimal with a restriction condition that max allowable with a condition that if length for decimal if is null or not present we need to take default value as (10,0) and if value present is greater than 38 we need to take default value as (38,0)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach works fine.

I show you a full example that completes your code and the expected result.

You could introduce more variants into `val data`.

```scala
  /**
    * to obtain a tuple with precision and scale
    * @param precision Option[String]
    * @return (Int, Int)
    */
  def getDecimalScale(precision: Option[String]): (Int, Int) = {
    precision match {
      case Some(pr) => {
        pr.split(",").toList match {
          case List(h, _) if h.toInt >= 38 => (38,0)
          case List(h, t) => (h.toInt,t.head.toString.toInt)
          case _ => (10, 0)
        }
      }
      case None => (10, 0)
    }
  }
```

```scala
    val data = List(("object_number", "varchar", "100"), ("function_type", "varchar", "100"),
      ("hof_1", "decimal", "17,3"), ("hof_2", "decimal", "17,2"),
      ("hof_3", "decimal", null),("hof_4", "decimal", "39,2"),
      ("region", "varchar", "100"), ("country", "varchar", null))

    import spark.implicits._

    val column_name = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("name","datatype","length")

    column_name.show()
/*
+-------------+--------+------+
|         name|datatype|length|
+-------------+--------+------+
|object_number| varchar|   100|
|function_type| varchar|   100|
|        hof_1| decimal|  17,3|
|        hof_2| decimal|  17,2|
|        hof_3| decimal|  null|
|        hof_4| decimal|  39,2|
|       region| varchar|   100|
|      country| varchar|  null|
+-------------+--------+------+
*/

    val schemaColumns = column_name.collect()
    schemaColumns.foreach(println)
/*
[object_number,varchar,100]
[function_type,varchar,100]
[hof_1,decimal,17,3]
[hof_2,decimal,17,2]
[hof_3,decimal,null]
[hof_4,decimal,39,2]
[region,varchar,100]
[country,varchar,null]
*/

    val schema = schemaColumns.foldLeft(new StructType())(
      (schema, columnRow) => {
        columnRow.getAs[String]("datatype") match {
          case "varchar" => schema.add(columnRow.getAs[String]("name"), StringType, true)
          case "decimal" => {
            val (pr, sc) = getDecimalScale(Option(columnRow.getAs[String]("length")))
            schema.add(columnRow.getAs[String]("name"), new DecimalType(precision = pr, scale = sc), true)
          }
          case _ => schema.add(columnRow.getAs[String]("name"), StringType, true)
        }
      }
    )

    schema.printTreeString()
/*
root
 |-- object_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- function_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hof_1: decimal(17,3) (nullable = true)
 |-- hof_2: decimal(17,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- hof_3: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- hof_4: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Chema for sharing the solution its working as expected

Comment: Hi @Mahi, if it was useful, please you might upvote, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal datatype with precision can be created as specified [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html):

```
 DataTypes.createDecimalType()
```

In function "getFieldType" case for Decimal type can be added, smth. like:

```
case "decimal" => DataTypes.createDecimalType(10,0)
```

Comment: hi pasha thanks for your kind response but i want the (p,s) to be taken dynamically from lenght and not a default value of (10,0), basically i would like to pass length also to function

`def getFieldType(typeName: String): DataType = typeName match {
    case "varchar" => StringType
    // TODO include other types here
    case _ => StringType
  }
`

Comment: additional parameter can be added to function "getFieldType" and used only for "decimal" field.

Comment: hi pasha i tried sending the field to function like below, can you show how to access 

`def getFieldType(typeName: String, length: String): DataType = typeName match {     case "varchar" => StringType 
case "decimal" => { 
          precision = Length.split(",")(0).toInt
          scale = Length.split(",")(1).toInt
          DecimalType(precision,scale)
 }`